# Javascript promise chaining with repeating logic appending to same item array

Tags: javascript, typescript

Various parts of the chain repeat depending on structure. For example, the site can have two subsites each with two lists. This means that the last chain will trigger four times. Where/how can I get the template object after all the inner changes have executed so that I have the complete templates collection?

```
    let promises = [];
    let templates:ITemplate[] = [];

    pnp.sp.web.webs.get().then(sites => {
      sites.forEach(site => {
        pnp.sp.site.openWebById(site.Id).then(result => {
          result.web.lists.get().then(lists => {
            lists.forEach(list => {
              promises.push(result.web.lists.getByTitle(list.Title).items.get());
            });
            Promise.all(promises)
            .then((results) => {
               // This runs multiple times which makes sense but I need the final templates array
               results.forEach(items => {
                items.forEach(item => {            
                  let template:ITemplate= {
                    Title:item.Title,
                    ...
                    ...
                  };
                  templates.push(template);
                });

                // If I add function here it runs multiple times which is not the desired outcome
                doSomethingWithTemplates(templates);
              });
            })
          })
        })
      });
    })

// Then do something with templates item collection that is a single item array with all items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im sure you can see from the problem you are having the disadvantages of chaining promises - maybe an approach similar to mine below using `async/await` will make it more clear how to solve your problem?

`Async/await` are effectively built on top of promises and still use promises. [This](https://javascript.info/async-await) gives you an idea if you dont already know.

```
async function insertName():Promise<ITemplate[]> {
    let promises = [];
    let templates:ITemplate[] = [];
    const sites = await pnp.sp.web.webs.get()
    sites.forEach(site => {
        const result = await pnp.sp.site.openWebById(site.Id)
        const lists = await result.web.lists.get()
        lists.forEach(list => {
            const toPush = await result.web.lists.getByTitle(list.Title).items.get()
            promises.push(toPush);
        })
        const results = await Promise.all(promises)
        results.forEach(items => {
            items.forEach(item => {            
                let template:ITemplate= {
                    Title:item.Title,
                    ...
                    ...
                };
                templates.push(template);
            });
            doSomethingWithTemplates(templates);
        });
    })
    return templates
}
const templates: ITemplate[] = await insertName()
```

Comment: I had to add async to the internal arrow functions and I dropped the promises array. Your answer was spot on.

Comment: No worries - glad it helped!